# Deadlock error in golang

Tags: go, deadlock

I recently looked at go and got hooked, it looks so interesting! After completing the tutorial I wanted to build something by myself: I want to list all of my songs from my music library. I think I can profit from go's concurrency here. While on routine is walking down the directory tree it pushes music files (path to those files) into a channel which are then picked up by another routine that reads the ID3 tags, so I don't have to wait until every file has been found.

This is my simple and naive approach:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

const searchPath = "/Users/luma/Music/test" // 5GB of music.

func main() {
    files := make(chan string)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    go printHashes(files, &wg)
    go searchFiles(searchPath, files, &wg)

    wg.Wait()
}

func searchFiles(searchPath string, files chan<- string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    visit := func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if !f.IsDir() && strings.Contains(".mp4.mp3.flac", filepath.Ext(f.Name())) {
            files <- path
        }
        return err
    }

    if err := filepath.Walk(searchPath, visit); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    wg.Done()
}

func printHashes(files <-chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for range files {
        fmt.Println(<-files)
    }

    wg.Done()
}
```

This program doesn't read the tags, yet. Instead it just prints the file path. This works, it lists all music files extremely fast! But I see this error after the program finishes:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc42007205c)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.4_2/libexec/src/runtime/sema.go:47 +0x30
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc420072050)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.4_2/libexec/src/sync/waitgroup.go:131 +0x97
main.main()
    /Users/luma/Code/Go/src/github.com/LuMa/test/main.go:22 +0xfa

goroutine 17 [chan receive]:
main.printHashes(0xc42008e000, 0xc420072050)
    /Users/luma/Code/Go/src/github.com/LuMa/test/main.go:42 +0xb4
created by main.main
    /Users/luma/Code/Go/src/github.com/LuMa/test/main.go:19 +0xab
exit status 2
```

What is causing the deadlock?

Comment: Always defer the WaitGroup.Done(). You have a return path in your first goroutine that doesn't call Done.

Comment: @JimB that almost got me too. But note that it isn't a return path - it's an inline func declared and passed into another function - which only has one execution path.  But yes, typical practices call for calling `defer wg.Done()`

Comment: @eduncan911: oops, thanks. Just scanned for early returns and didn't read closely enough.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `searchFiles`, you want to `close(files)` when done sending.  This convention is called sender-closes (receivers never close).  Also, remove the call to `wg.Done()` as you are not done... There could still be items on the channel.

The `close(files)` will signal the `for range files` to close and exit the loop, which will call your `wg.Done()` to signal the main function that everything is done.

(Untested on mobile)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

const searchPath = "/Users/luma/Music/test" // 5GB of music.

func main() {
    files := make(chan string)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)

    go printHashes(files)
    go searchFiles(searchPath, files, &wg)

    wg.Wait()
}

func searchFiles(searchPath string, files chan<- string) {
    visit := func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if !f.IsDir() && strings.Contains(".mp4.mp3.flac", filepath.Ext(f.Name())) {
            files <- path
        }
        return err
    }

    if err := filepath.Walk(searchPath, visit); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    close(files)
}

func printHashes(files <-chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for range files {
        fmt.Println(<-files)
    }
}
```

Note that while this may seem fast, using a single goroutine is fine and unblocks the main goroutine too.  But, you may not gain any advantage if you try to read multiple files for id3 tags in multiple goroutines - they will all share the same file i/o lock at the syscall level.  The only way that would advantageous would be if the processing of data far out weighs the file i/o locking (e.g. something big in computation, because processing is far faster than syscall locks).

PS, welcome to the Go community!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the hint about syscall level file locks. My initial idea was, that walking the directory tree of a 500GB music library might take some time. So why not start reading tags (which is far slower) as early as possible.

Comment: @LuMa Actually, reading MP3 Tags is pretty damn fast.  It's well know the bytecode offsets of the MP3 tag within an MP3.  And therefore, it's a quick `open file -> read byte offset locations -> close file` operation.  syscalls will still be the major lock, which will be the performance killer.  Unless... they are on different drives.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Because you need close `files` channel.
In your case, you don't close it, so

`for range files {
     fmt.Println(<-files)
 }`  will wait get value from `files` channel. so `wg.Done()` will never done in `printHashes`.

```
func searchFiles(searchPath string, files chan<- string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    visit := func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if !f.IsDir() && strings.Contains(".mp4.mp3.flac", filepath.Ext(f.Name())) {
            files <- path
        }
        return err
    }

    if err := filepath.Walk(searchPath, visit); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    wg.Done()
    close(files) // close the chanel, because you don't put thing into the channel anymore.
}
```