# Mulithreading within recursive function is slower

Tags: go, concurrency, parallel-processing, system-calls

```
var m sync.Mutex

func recurseDirectoriesMultiThread(wg *sync.WaitGroup, photoPaths *[]string, directory string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    items, _ := os.ReadDir(directory)
    for _, item := range items {
        if item.IsDir() {
            wg.Add(1)
            go recurseDirectoriesMultiThread(wg, photoPaths, directory+"/"+item.Name())
        } else {
            // handle file
            m.Lock()
            *photoPaths = append(*photoPaths, directory+"/"+item.Name())
            m.Unlock()
        }
    }

}
func recurseDirectories(photoPaths *[]string, directory string) {
    items, _ := os.ReadDir(directory)
    for _, item := range items {
        if item.IsDir() {
            recurseDirectories(photoPaths, directory+"/"+item.Name())
        } else {
            // handle file
            *photoPaths = append(*photoPaths, directory+"/"+item.Name())
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    args := os.Args
    fmt.Println(args[1])
    path := args[1]

    stringSlice1 := make([]string, 0) // slice
    start := time.Now()
    recurseDirectories(&stringSlice1, path)
    fmt.Println("Single thread time " + time.Since(start).String())
    fmt.Println("Number of files " + strconv.Itoa(len(stringSlice1)))

    stringSlice2 := make([]string, 0) // slice
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    wg.Add(1)
    start = time.Now()
    recurseDirectoriesMultiThread(wg, &stringSlice2, path)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Mulit thread time " + time.Since(start).String())
    fmt.Println("Number of files " + strconv.Itoa(len(stringSlice2)))
}
```

I wanted to try out a project to learn more about goroutines and channels. I thought a system file scanner would be a cool idea to gain all file names within a directory. Although now I am seeing it might not be as performant as I'd thought https://stackoverflow.com/a/41687429/13970153 because there will be file i/o lock at the syscall level regardless of my approach. Regardless of that, for some odd reason I see my mutli threaded method here continuously being less performant then the normal recursive method. I thought it would be faster to some small degree at least?

Output:

```
Mulit thread time 224.196833ms
Number of files 3123
Single thread time 147.0

Mulit thread time 228.218042ms
Number of files 3123
Single thread time 149.666041ms
Number of files 3123

Mulit thread time 185.23275ms
Number of files 3123
Single thread time 147.412958ms
Number of files 3123
```

Does anyone have any ideas.

I did not see the reason to use channels here since I can just lock and unlock a mutex for `photoPaths`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used lock/unlock for every addition to the common list, it is likely that all goroutines wait each other to write to the list. Because of that, your algorithm is not really benefitting from multiple goroutines, because the amount of time spent finding files is comparable to the amount of time spent waiting writing to the list.

Try returning a new slice from each goroutine with many files in it, and use the lock to append one list to another, and then measure. That should increase the parallelism as each goroutine will work independently to fill a new slice.